# List content of one or more files with a header showing the file name

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, utility

Sometime ago I read a blog that showed a *misuse* of a commandline command that when given a list of files serially showed the content of each file and each file had header line showing the filename of the file below it. Could someone refresh my memory?

Comment: You mean, something other than `for file in *.txt; do echo "$file"; cat "$file"; done`?

Comment: Oh, or maybe `head -n -0 *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `tail` or `head` for this: when given multiple files, both tools precede each file's contents with a header containing the file name.

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo line$i > file$i; done
$ tail file*
==> file1 <==
line1

==> file2 <==
line2

==> file3 <==
line3
```

To output the entire files instead of just the last/first 10 lines of each, use `tail -n +1` or `head -n -0`.